# Custom pipe in Angular not working for every element - Only displays on the last element in for loop

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create my fist custom pipe in Angular. And I have an issue that I cant seem to solve. I have a for loop that and then applying my custom pipe to do a websocket call that should present data about many elements. But it only gives me one observable there in the template, its the last element. So Im guessing it overwrited every time the loop goes. Can someone please help me understand what Im doing wrong here:

**This is my custom pipe ts file:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, Subject, of } from "rxjs";

import { BinanceWsService } from 'src/app/shared/services/binance-ws.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'pricePipe',
  pure: false
})
export class PricePipe implements PipeTransform {
  public price!: Subject<string>;
  pricex!: Observable<string>;

  constructor(
    public binanceWsService: BinanceWsService
  ) {
    
  }

  transform(value: string, ...args: any[]): any {
    return this.price(value);
  }

  price(symbol: string): Observable<string> {
    const URL = `wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/${symbol}usdt@markPrice`

    this.price = <Subject<string>>this.binanceWsService
      .connect(URL)
      .pipe(map((response: MessageEvent): string => {
        let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        return data.p;
      }
    ));

    this.price.subscribe(msg => {
      console.log(symbol + ': ' + msg)
      this.pricex = of(msg);
    })

    return this.pricex;
  }

}
```

**This is how I try access it inside a for loop:**

```
{{ c.symbol | pricePipe | async | number}}
```

Comment: It is not usual to make API calls within a pipe - read the first paragraph of https://angular.io/guide/pipes for their intended use.

Comment: @wlf Alright, but where should that be if I need to loop through first _what_ elements should be in the template and then get the data. What would be an appropriate approach?

Comment: I would use rxjs, assuming you are getting the original  items from a service - then pipe through a switchmap to call the binance API and map to a combined object. Result is an observable list of those combined objects which you can present in the template via async pipe.

Answer (score -1):

Calling an API is not a good use for a pipe: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

*Use pipes to **transform** strings, currency amounts, dates, and other data for display. Pipes are simple functions…*

A better approach is to use rxjs to aggregate the data before display.

In your component TS:

```
let symbols$ = getSymbolsFromService();
let pricedSymbols$ = symbols$.pipe(
  map((symbols) =>
    symbols.map((symbol) =>
      getPriceFromBinance(symbol).pipe(map((price) => ({ symbol, price })))
    )
  ),
  mergeMap((pricedSymbols$) => forkJoin(pricedSymbols$))
);
```

- use plain JS array `map` to call the price service for each symbol in the list
- combine the price result with the matching symbol
- use `mergeMap` and `forkJoin` to combine the items back into a single object for emission by `pricedSymbols$`

In your template:

```
<div *ngFor=“let s of pricedSymbols$ | async”>
 {{ s.symbol }}
 {{ s.price }}
</div>
```

Stackblitz(check console tab for output): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dqymgd